# jQuery targeting data-post_id

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following div and form:

```
<?php echo '<div class="special" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ;?>
    <h2 class="title">
       <?php the_title(); ?> 
    </h2>                               
</div>                  

<form>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
  <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_id">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now in jQuery:

```
 var title   = jQuery('#title').val();
 var post_id   = jQuery('#post_id').val();
 ...
 success : function(data){
     jQuery('.title ??????').html(title);                   
 }
```

So, when the form is submitted, I want to replace the `<h2>` with the input field (title in this case).

Because the form will have a specific `post_id`, I want to find the `div` with the same `data-post_id`.

How do I target the div with the same `post_id` as the form `post_id` based on the `data-post_id`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually you can do this, that should do the trick:

```
 var title   = jQuery('#title').val();
 var post_id   = jQuery('#post_id').val();
 ...
 success : function(data){
     jQuery('h2[data-post_id="' + post_id + '"] .title').html(title);                   
 }
```